# Ethernet not working with 2 interfaces at a time

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet

My setup:

- Mother board has 4 PCIe slot: PCIe0/1(x16), PCIe2/3(x8), PCIe4/5(x16), PCIe6(x1)
- Two I210 ethernet cards: one on PCIe6 slot, one on PCIe2 slot
- One Mellanox card on PCIe0 slot (might not be relevant because Mellanox card is loopback set-up)

Try to ping server with set-up remote server (in this case: 10.76.176.193)
     + Ping with I210 card on PCIe2 successful:

```
ping -I enP2p1s0 10.76.176.193
PING 10.76.176.193 (10.76.176.193) from 10.76.190.205 enP2p1s0: 56(84) 
bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.535 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.361 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.316 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.334 ms

--- 10.76.176.193 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.316/0.386/0.535/0.089 ms

 + Ping with I210 card on PCIe6 failed: 
ping -I enP6p1s0 10.76.176.193
PING 10.76.176.193 (10.76.176.193) from 10.76.190.210 enP6p1s0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.76.176.193 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4999ms
```

`ifconfig` output

```
enP2p1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.76.190.205  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.76.190.255
    inet6 fe80::b2c6:fe34:cba8:f02f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether a0:36:9f:d7:71:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 622406  bytes 734503804 (700.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 559815  bytes 729105591 (695.3 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0x1080000000-10800fffff

enP6p1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.76.190.210  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.76.190.255
    inet6 fe80::f9f1:9c32:866f:dc1a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether a0:36:9f:d7:73:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 36200  bytes 3105207 (2.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1830  bytes 87880 (85.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0x680000000-6800fffff

enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.50.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.50.0.255
    inet6 fe80::f652:14ff:fe0b:d230  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether f4:52:14:0b:d2:30  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 354914  bytes 124335944 (118.5 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 22222959  bytes 33472688082 (31.1 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0d1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 11.50.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 11.50.0.255
    inet6 fe80::f652:14ff:fe0b:d231  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether f4:52:14:0b:d2:31  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 22222919  bytes 33472684938 (31.1 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 354954  bytes 124339088 (118.5 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 16  bytes 1360 (1.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 16  bytes 1360 (1.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

After that, I tried `ifconfig enP2p1s0 down` and retry ping successful with I210 slot PCIe6:

```
ifconfig enP2p1s0 down
ping -I enP6p1s0 10.76.176.193
PING 10.76.176.193 (10.76.176.193) from 10.76.190.210 enP6p1s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.400 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.380 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.339 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.301 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.321 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=0.360 ms
64 bytes from 10.76.176.193: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=0.308 ms

--- 10.76.176.193 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6000ms
```

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.301/0.344/0.400/0.036 ms

Output of `ip route` (PASS case):

```
ip route list
default via 10.76.190.1 dev enP6p1s0  proto static  metric 101
10.50.0.0/24 dev enp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.50.0.1
10.51.0.1 dev enp1s0d1  scope link
10.76.18.11 via 10.76.190.1 dev enP6p1s0  proto dhcp  metric 100
10.76.190.0/24 dev enP6p1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src         10.76.190.210  metric 100
11.50.0.0/24 dev enp1s0d1  proto kernel  scope link  src 11.50.0.1
11.51.0.1 dev enp1s0  scope link
```

Then I tried `ifconfig enP2p1s0 up`, fail ping again:

```
ifconfig enP2p1s0 up
[67249.376503] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enP2p1s0: link is not ready
[root@dhcp-10-76-190-205 mipham]# [67252.028125] igb 0002:01:00.0 enP2p1s0: igb: enP2p1s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[67252.038150] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enP2p1s0: link becomes ready
ping -I enP6p1s0 10.76.176.193
PING 10.76.176.193 (10.76.176.193) from 10.76.190.210 enP6p1s0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.76.176.193 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

Output of `ip route` (FAIL case):

```
ip route list
default via 10.76.190.1 dev enP2p1s0  proto static  metric 100
default via 10.76.190.1 dev enP6p1s0  proto static  metric 101
10.50.0.0/24 dev enp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.50.0.1
10.51.0.1 dev enp1s0d1  scope link
10.76.18.11 via 10.76.190.1 dev enP6p1s0  proto dhcp  metric 100
10.76.190.0/24 dev enP6p1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.76.190.210  metric 100
10.76.190.0/24 dev enP2p1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.76.190.205  metric 101
11.50.0.0/24 dev enp1s0d1  proto kernel  scope link  src 11.50.0.1
```

It seems those 2 ports conflict each other in some sense but I don't know the cause and how to run both at the same time.

Can someone tell me what could be the cause and how to fix this (run both ports at the same time). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question directly, but probably you can look into the following two perspectives:

1. Check and make sure both cards are using IPv4 (the IPv6 messages you got when "ifconfig enP2p1s0 up" is a bit strange)
2. May be you want to check out the [NIC bonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding), which I am also trying to figure out on how to utilize all three Ethernet cards. ^_^